# Recycle vector to specific length

Tags: r, rep

I would like to simply recycle a vector to a given length (see below). The below function is inspired by `OpenRepGrid::recycle`, but I struggle to believe that this is the best way to get there, given that recycling is so fundamental.

I am looking for a pure base R solution, and it should be simpler/ faster/ more efficient than the approach below.

```r
recycle <- function(x, new_length){
rep(x, ceiling(new_length/length(x)))[1:new_length]
}

## desired effect
recycle(c("red", "blue", "green"), 10)
#>  [1] "red"   "blue"  "green" "red"   "blue"  "green" "red"   "blue"  "green"
#> [10] "red"
```

Comment: `rep(c("red", "blue", "green"), length.out = 10)`.

Comment: Or probably even more effective `rep_len(x, 10)`.

Comment: I don't think there are simpler answers than the top two ones in the comment. Here are some other proposals `x[(seq(10) - 1) %% 3 + 1]` or `x[gl(3, 1, 10)]`